# Why am I getting Next Js hydration error?

Tags: next.js, hydration, react-swiper

I am trying to make an web app and using react swiper fot it, but it is causing hydration. When I comment out the react swiper then I don't see the error.

I am getting "Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Zach N." Client: "Lisa A." in the console.

Can someone help me to fix it????
Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

thanks in advance.

```
// Slider
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css"; // You can also use <link> for styles

function Testimonials() {
  const sliderRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1500,
    });
  });

  const handlePrev = useCallback(() => {
    if (!sliderRef.current) return;
    sliderRef.current.swiper.slidePrev();
  }, []);

  const handleNext = useCallback(() => {
    if (!sliderRef.current) return;
    sliderRef.current.swiper.slideNext();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="lg:h-[80vh] lg:pt-16 ">
        <div data-aos="fade-up">
          <h2 className="text-[40px] xl:text-[70px] leading-[44px] lx:leading-[70px] mt-[70px] mb-[15px] md:mb-[19px] font-bold font-FreightSemibold ">
            Today&apos;s news.Edited to be{" "}
            <span className="italic block xl:mt-7">
              unbiased as humanly possible.
            </span>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div data-aos="fade-up" className="flex lg:justify-between">
          <div className="w-[600px]">
            <p className="xl:text-[20px]">
              Every morning, we triple check headlines, stories and sources for
              bias. All by hand, no algorithms.{" "}
              <span className="font-bold">See what readers are saying:</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="hidden md:flex ">
            <div
              onClick={handlePrev}
              className="w-[55.84px] h-[55.84px] group rounded-full flex cursor-pointer hover:bg-black  md:mx-[18px] justify-center items-center ring-1 ring-black "
            >
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className="h-6 w-6 group-hover:text-white"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                strokeWidth={2}
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M7 16l-4-4m0 0l4-4m-4 4h18"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div
              onClick={handleNext}
              className="w-[55.84px] h-[55.84px] group rounded-full flex cursor-pointer justify-center items-center hover:bg-black  ring-1 ring-black "
            >
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className="h-6 w-6 group-hover:text-white"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                strokeWidth={2}
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M17 8l4 4m0 0l-4 4m4-4H3"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* Slider Here */}
        <div className="md:flex">
          <Swiper
            ref={sliderRef}
            loop={true}
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            slidesPerView={1}
            spaceBetween={10}
            breakpoints={{
              "@0.00": {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10,
              },
              "@0.75": {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 20,
              },
              "@1.00": {
                slidesPerView: 3,
                spaceBetween: 40,
              },
              "@1.50": {
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 50,
              },
            }}
          >
              <SwiperSlide>
              <div data-aos="fade-left" className="mt-[80px] md:mx-5 mb-[45px]">
                <div className="border-black mb-[40px] border-b-[1px] ">
                  <h3 className="font-bold py-1">Lisa A.</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-[40px]">
                  <p>
                    “I consider myself a centrist - all the other news sources
                    lean so far to the left or right, it makes my head spin.
                    Thank you for{" "}
                    <span className={`bg-[#6fef8d]`}>
                      providing strictly the facts
                    </span>{" "}
                    - you re the only news source that can actually pull off
                    neutrality these days.”
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div data-aos="fade-left" className="mt-[80px] md:mx-2 mb-[45px]">
                <div className="border-black mb-[40px] border-b-[1px] ">
                  <h3 className="font-bold py-1">Emma S.</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-[40px]">
                  <p>
                    “I consider myself a centrist - all the other news sources
                    lean so far to the left or right, it makes my head spin.
                    Thank you for{" "}
                    <span className={`bg-[#EFEF6F]`}>
                      providing strictly the facts
                    </span>{" "}
                    - you re the only news source that can actually pull off
                    neutrality these days.”
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div data-aos="fade-left" className="mt-[80px] md:mx-5 mb-[45px]">
                <div className="border-black mb-[40px] border-b-[1px] ">
                  <h3 className="font-bold py-1">Jim M.</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-[40px]">
                  <p>
                    “I stopped watching the news, so sick of the bias. Was
                    searching for an alternative that would just tell me WHAT
                    happened, with NO editorializing. I found it. It s called
                    1440. It assumes you are smart enough to{" "}
                    <span className={`bg-[#7EDCF2]`}>
                      form your own opinions.
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div data-aos="fade-left" className="mt-[80px] md:mx-5 mb-[45px]">
                <div className="border-black mb-[40px] border-b-[1px] ">
                  <h3 className="font-bold py-1">Zach N.</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-[40px]">
                  <p className="">
                    “I stopped my habit of spending my day doomscrolling. I
                    signed up for 1440 &{" "}
                    <span className={`bg-[#F48CD9]`}>
                      {" "}
                      feel better informed in less time.
                    </span>{" "}
                    I m also less stressed out. Thank you.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Testimonials;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `slidesPerView={1}` by  `slidesPerView="auto"`

Also update your AOS init like this to avoid infinite loop

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1500,
    });
  },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar error in NextJS 13 and Swiper dependency, not in dev mode but in the build bundle, I tried different approaches (including the useEffect mentioned in NextJS documentation) the way that worked for me was disabling SSR (also mentioned on NextJS doc) on Components that use Swiper:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

const NoSSRServices = dynamic(() => import("../components/services/Services"), {
  ssr: false,
})
const NoSSRBanner = dynamic(() => import("../components/banner/Banner"), {
  ssr: false,
})

function Home({ sliderData, photographerData, servicesData, miniGalleryHome }) {
  return ( 
    <Layout>
        <NoSSRBanner sliderData={sliderData} />
        <About photographerData={photographerData} />
        <Portfolio miniGalleryHome={miniGalleryHome} />
        <NoSSRServices servicesData={servicesData} />
        <Faqs />
    </Layout>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps() {//no relevant code for this 
problem context}

export default Home
```

Hope my solution Helps, if there is a better option don't hesitate to comment on it.